# How to Push more item to Array values in Hashmap in javascript

Tags: javascript

there 'bar' key in hashmap which has an array its value which has one item in it ['foo'] later I want to add one more item 'foo1' to the same array Is following code right approach or there is any other Simple way to achieve it?

```js
var map1 = new Map();
map1.set('bar', ['foo']);
var newValues = map1.get("bar");   
map1.set('bar' ,newValues.concat('foo1'));
console.log(map1.get('bar')); // ['foo', 'foo1']
```

Comment: how about map1.set('bar', ['foo','foo1']);
what exacly you trying to achive

Comment: @PanosK I have edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2 lines simplier

```
var map1 = new Map();
map1.set('bar', ['foo']);
map1.get('bar').push('foo1')
```